# Wigner-Weyl transformation for particle in magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, wigner-transform

I consider particle in external magnetic field, ${\bf A}=(-yB,0,0)$ and find wave functions (may be up to normalization factors),
$$\psi(x,y,z)=\sum_n\sum_s\int\frac{dp_xdp_z}{(2\pi)^2}f_s\left(eBy+p_x\right)e^{ip_xx+ip_zz},$$
where $f(eBy+p_x,n)$ is Hermite polynomial (up to numerical factors) and $n$ labels Landau's level and it is two-component spinor with eigenvalues $s=\pm 1$ ($\sigma_zf_s=sf_s$) . Then I consider the following quantitiy,
$$G({\bf r}_1,t_1;{\bf r}_2,t_2)=\Psi^{\dagger}(x_2,y_,z_2,t_2)\Psi(x_1,y_1,z_1,t_1),\qquad \Psi=\psi e^{iE_nt},$$
where $E_n$ is an energy of particle. I would like to understand how should I define Wigner-Weyl transformation for this problem. Naively, I introduce "centered" coordinates ${\bf r}=({\bf r}_1+{\bf r}_2)/2$ and $\delta{\bf r}={\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2$ and similarly for time variables. Then, I suppose that my function becomes
$$G({\bf r},t;{\bf q},\omega_0)=\int\frac{d^3\delta{\bf r}}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{d\delta t}{(2\pi)}e^{i\delta{\bf r}\cdot{\bf q}}e^{-i\delta t\omega_0}G({\bf r}_1,t_1;{\bf r}_2,t_2).$$
However, I feel that it is not correct. Can someone provide references for this topic? I try to google it, but it was unsuccesful.

**Question**: how one should define Wigner-Weyl transformation for electron in external magnetic field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology of 1d, 2d spaces is very different than 3d, so the solutions preferred are very different... Wilson lines act very differently in different dimensions.

- [Kubo 1964](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/Kubo64.pdf).
- A cheap/pedagogical [talk of ours, 1999](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903254)
- The real, 3d, Mc Coy:  M Müller, J Phys A32 (1999) 1035-1052 ;  M Karasev and T Osborn, Jou Math Phys 43 (2002) 756-788 [quant-ph/0002041](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0002041);
  J Phys A37 (2004) 2345-2363 [quant-ph/0311053](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0311053);  [ibid A38 (2005) 8549-8578](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/38/40/006).
- Also see: M Mantoiu and R Purice, J Math Phys 45 (2004) 1394-1416  .
- Finally, you can really use these Wigner functions for Landau orbits without even acknowledging them directly, [D J Callaway 1990](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(90)90672-Z), [D J Callaway 1992](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000349169290287V).

This is a deep and recondite subject, so I am just throwing in references, but no insight; I have found, in the past, that my focus is virtually orthogonal to that of other aficionados. Anything authored by/with Tom Osborn is  quite tasteful.

Comment: Thank You, Prof. Zachos, I will check these references. To be specific, I am dealing with Wigner-Weyl transform for $G^{-+}$ Green function (if it makes sense) of electron in external magnetic field (3+1 space-time).